# Revit Python Shell - Change Parameter Group

Tags: revitpythonshell

I'm trying to write a quick script to open a family document, change the parameter group of 2 specified parameters, and then close and save the document. I've done multiple tests and I am able to change the parameter groups of the specified parameters, but the changes of the groups don't save back to the family file. When I open the newly saved family, the parameter groups revert back to their original group.

This is with Revit 2017.2.

The same script, when run in RPS in Revit 2018 will do as desired.

```
import clr
import os
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import UIApplication

from System.IO import Directory, SearchOption

searchstring = "*.rfa"
dir = r"C:\Users\dboghean\Desktop\vanity\2017"

docs = []

if Directory.Exists(dir):
    files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, searchstring, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for f in files:
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
        name2, extension2 = os.path.splitext(name)
        if extension2:
            os.remove(f)
        else:
            docs.append(f)
else:
    print("Directory does not exist")

doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
app = __revit__.Application
uiapp = UIApplication(app)

currentPath = doc.PathName

pgGroup = BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_GRAPHICS

for i in docs:

    doc = app.OpenDocumentFile(i)

    paramList = [i for i in doc.FamilyManager.Parameters]

    t = Transaction(doc, "test")
    t.Start()

    for i in paramList:
        if i.Definition.Name in ["Right Sidesplash Edge line", "Left Sidesplash Edge line"]:
            i.Definition.ParameterGroup = pgGroup

    t.Commit()

    doc.Close(True)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there evidence that the RFA actually saved? ie. a .0001.rfa backup? Does it work when you manually open, run the script on the opened file, then manually save?

Comment: There is a .0001.rfa backup that is created and the modified date is updated to when the file is saved, so that leads me to believe that the file is indeed successfully saved.

I just tried manually opening the file, running the script, and manually saving, and that did not work. Again, the script ran successfully, the parameter group was changed, but after saving, closing and reopening the file, it reverted to the previous parameter group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this happens in Revit 2017. Strange!

A simple way around it is to arbitrarily rename the parameter using `doc.FamilyManager.RenameParameter`, then rename it back to the original name.

So in your case this would be three additional lines of code after changing the Parameter group:

```
originalName = i.Definition.Name
doc.FamilyManager.RenameParameter(i, "temp")
doc.FamilyManager.RenameParameter(i, originalName)
```

Doesnt get to the root problem, but works around it

Comment: That did it! 

Thank you. Not sure what the error is, but that's a simple enough workaround.